# SQL Query - SUM(CASE WHEN x THEN 1 ELSE 0) for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I'm looking to see if there is a better approach to the query below.  What I'm trying to do is create a summary report, compiling stats by date.

```
 SELECT CAST(Detail.ReceiptDate AS DATE) AS 'DATE'
, SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.Type = 'TotalMailed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTALMAILED'
, SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.Type = 'TotalReturnMail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED'
, SUM(CASE WHEN Detail.Type = 'TraceReturnedMail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED'
FROM
(
select SentDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 'TotalMailed' AS 'Type'
from MailDataExtract
where sentdate is not null
UNION ALL
select MDE.ReturnMailDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 'TotalReturnMail' AS 'Type'
from MailDataExtract MDE
where MDE.ReturnMailDate is not null
UNION ALL
select MDE.ReturnMailDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 'TraceReturnedMail' AS 'Type'
from MailDataExtract MDE
    inner join DTSharedData.dbo.ScanData SD ON SD.ScanDataID = MDE.ReturnScanDataID
where MDE.ReturnMailDate is not null AND SD.ReturnMailTypeID = 1
) AS Detail
GROUP BY CAST(Detail.ReceiptDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY 1
```

This is only a sample of the query (which is used in a report) as there are a number of other columns and the logic for the other stats are way more complicated.  Is there a more elegant approach to getting this kind of information/writing this kind of report?

Comment: Is this in a proc or a view, or something else? Basically, can you introduce variables and run multiple statements, or is it just a big `select` statement?

Comment: It's a proc that will be used for a SSRS report, so it will need to essentially be a select statement as I need to return a result set (right?)

Comment: Yep, you'll eventually have a big `select` at the end, but since it's in a proc, you'll have the ability to break your query up into smaller, simpler chunks, assigning values to variables as you go along. This can make a big difference in readability. For example, rather than `union`ing or grouping these three subqueries, you can have three small standalone queries run in advance which assign summarized results to variables, then simply select those variables for your return query. Potentially a lot easier to read and understand, and possibly better performing as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would change the query in the following ways:

1. Do the aggregation in subqueries.  This can take advantage of more information about the table for optimizing the `group by`.
2. Combine the second and third subqueries.  They are aggregating on the same column.  This requires using a `left outer join` to ensure that all data is available.
3. By using `count(<fieldname>)` you can eliminate the comparisons to `is null`.  This is important for the second and third calculated values.
4. To combine the second and third queries, it needs to count an id from the `mde` table.  These use `mde.mdeid`.

The following version follows your example by using `union all`:

```
SELECT CAST(Detail.ReceiptDate AS DATE) AS "Date",
       SUM(TOTALMAILED) as TotalMailed,
       SUM(TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED) as TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED,
       SUM(TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED) as TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED
FROM ((select SentDate AS "ReceiptDate", COUNT(*) as TotalMailed,
              NULL as TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED, NULL as TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED
       from MailDataExtract
       where SentDate is not null
       group by SentDate
      ) union all
      (select MDE.ReturnMailDate AS ReceiptDate, 0,
              COUNT(distinct mde.mdeid) as TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED,
              SUM(case when sd.ReturnMailTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED
       from MailDataExtract MDE left outer join
            DTSharedData.dbo.ScanData SD
            ON SD.ScanDataID = MDE.ReturnScanDataID
       group by MDE.ReturnMailDate;
      )
     ) detail
GROUP BY CAST(Detail.ReceiptDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY 1;
```

The following does something similar using `full outer join`:

```
SELECT coalesce(sd.ReceiptDate, mde.ReceiptDate) AS "Date",
       sd.TotalMailed, mde.TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED,
       mde.TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED
FROM (select cast(SentDate as date) AS "ReceiptDate", COUNT(*) as TotalMailed
      from MailDataExtract
      where SentDate is not null
      group by cast(SentDate as date)
     ) sd full outer join
    (select cast(MDE.ReturnMailDate as date) AS ReceiptDate,
            COUNT(distinct mde.mdeID) as TOTALUNDELINOTICESRECEIVED,
            SUM(case when sd.ReturnMailTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TRACEUNDELNOTICESRECEIVED
     from MailDataExtract MDE left outer join
          DTSharedData.dbo.ScanData SD
          ON SD.ScanDataID = MDE.ReturnScanDataID
     group by cast(MDE.ReturnMailDate as date)
    ) mde
    on sd.ReceiptDate = mde.ReceiptDate
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a subquery to do grouping. In this case inner subquery returns few rows and you don't need a CASE statement. So I think this is going to be faster:

```
select Detail.ReceiptDate AS 'DATE',
       SUM(TotalMailed),
       SUM(TotalReturnMail),
       SUM(TraceReturnedMail)

from
(

select SentDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 
       count('TotalMailed') AS TotalMailed, 
       0 as TotalReturnMail, 
       0 as TraceReturnedMail
from MailDataExtract
where sentdate is not null
GROUP BY SentDate

UNION ALL
select MDE.ReturnMailDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 
       0 AS TotalMailed, 
       count(TotalReturnMail) as TotalReturnMail, 
       0 as TraceReturnedMail
from MailDataExtract MDE
where MDE.ReturnMailDate is not null
GROUP BY  MDE.ReturnMailDate

UNION ALL

select MDE.ReturnMailDate AS 'ReceiptDate', 
       0 AS TotalMailed, 
       0 as TotalReturnMail, 
       count(TraceReturnedMail) as TraceReturnedMail

from MailDataExtract MDE
    inner join DTSharedData.dbo.ScanData SD 
        ON SD.ScanDataID = MDE.ReturnScanDataID
   where MDE.ReturnMailDate is not null AND SD.ReturnMailTypeID = 1
GROUP BY MDE.ReturnMailDate

) as Detail
GROUP BY Detail.ReceiptDate
ORDER BY 1
```