# Returning counted columns with respect to another columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table with multiple columns; two of which i am selecting: "Operation_desc" and "new_rtg_no"

There are other columns acting as parameters and are hard coded as they will never change.

I'm trying to gather associated numbers and count how many there are of each number and associate it into a query being used in a SSRS report.

example of data in table

```
Operation   Rating
INS OPER    3.00
LAW         3.00
HUMAN RES   5.00
HUMAN RES   3.00
INFO SERVS  3.00
HUMAN RES   3.00
HUMAN RES   3.00
HUMAN RES   4.00
HUMAN RES   3.00
HUMAN RES   4.00
```

What I'm getting is what I'm essentially looking for but instead of individual operation counts I'm getting the whole count for an individual rating for the entire DB.  I know i can use CASE's to do what I want but that is going to take a whole bunch of sub queries that are going to slow everything down significantly.

Instead of This:

```
            Bonus Eligible          Exempt              Non-Exempt
OPERATION   R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  Ttl R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  Ttl R1 ... etc
INS OPER    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
LAW         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
HUMAN RES   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
Info Servs  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
COLMBS LF   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
CONTROLLER  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   9   3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   16  0   0   3   1   0   3
```

I want this:

```
                Bonus Eligible          Exempt              Non-Exempt
OPERATION   R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  Ttl R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  Ttl R1 ... etc
INS OPER    3   2   4   1   1   11  0   1   13  3   0   17  0   0   13  5   1   19  0   0   3   1   0   4
LAW         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   7   3   1   13  0   0   10  2   1   13  0   0   3   4   0   7
..... ETC
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OPERATION_DESC, (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
              FROM         EMPL
              WHERE     (NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND GRADE_CD = '50')) AS R1B,
           (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
            FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
            WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND GRADE_CD = '50' )) AS R2B,
           (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
            FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_3
            WHERE      (new_RTG_NO = 3 AND GRADE_CD = '50')) AS R3B,
           (SELECT     COUNT(new_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
            FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_2
            WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND GRADE_CD = '50')) AS R4B,
           (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
            FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_1
            WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND GRADE_CD = '50')) AS R5B
    , (select count(NEW_RTG_NO) as expr1 from empl where (grade_cd = '50')) AS TotalBonus
    , (SELECT COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM         EMPL
               WHERE     (NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E')) AS R1E,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
               WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' )) AS R2E,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_3
               WHERE      (new_RTG_NO = 3 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E')) AS R3E,
              (SELECT     COUNT(new_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_2
               WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E')) AS R4E,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_1
               WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E')) AS R5E
    , (select count(NEW_RTG_NO) as expr1 from empl where (FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E')) AS TotalExempt
    , (SELECT COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM         EMPL
               WHERE     (NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N')) AS R1N,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
               WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' )) AS R2N,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_3
                WHERE      (new_RTG_NO = 3 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N')) AS R3N,
              (SELECT     COUNT(new_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_2
                WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N')) AS R4N,
              (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
               FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_1
               WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N')) AS R5N
    , (select count(NEW_RTG_NO) as expr1 from empl where (FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N')) AS TotalNonExempt
    , (SELECT COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                FROM         EMPL
                WHERE     (NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P')) AS R1P,
               (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                  FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
                  WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' )) AS R2P,
               (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                 FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_3
                 WHERE      (new_RTG_NO = 3 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P')) AS R3P,
               (SELECT     COUNT(new_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                 FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_2
                 WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P')) AS R4P,
               (SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
                 FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_1
                 WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P')) AS R5P
    , (select count(NEW_RTG_NO) as expr1 
                from empl 
                where (FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P')) AS TotalPT
 FROM         EMPL AS E
 group by E.OPERATION_DESC ORDER BY E.OPERATION_DESC
```

Now my question is:  Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do without having to use a CASE statement and copy and paste this 40 times for each individual case.  I'm also open to ways of doing this in SSRS with a simple query if that would be easier.

Final Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OPERATION_DESC, 
SUM(Case when NEW_RTG_NO = 1 and GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end) AS R1B,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end) AS R2B,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 3 AND GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end) AS R3B,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end) AS R4B,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end) AS R5B,
SUM(case when GRADE_CD = '50' then 1 else 0 end ) AS TotalBonus,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) AS R1E,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) AS R2E,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 3 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) AS R3E,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) AS R4E,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) AS R5E,
SUM(case when FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' then 1 else 0 end ) AS TotalExempt,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R1N,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R2N,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 3 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R3N,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R4N,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R5N,
SUM(case when FLSA_STAT_CD = 'N' then 1 else 0 end ) AS TotalNonExempt,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R1P,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R2P,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 3 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R3P,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R4P,
SUM(case when NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS R5P,
SUM(case when FULL_OR_PART_TM_IND = 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) AS TotalPT
FROM EMPL
GROUP BY OPERATION_DESC 
ORDER BY OPERATION_DESC
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve. In the two tables that you compare, where do the numbers in the second table come from? Why would a query produce those instead of the first table?

Also, are you really using a MySQL server for this, or is it all on MS SQL Server? (Tag indicates MySQL is involved.

Comment: Didn't realize it was also tagged with MySQL, edited.  Also to answer your question, the second "table" is derived from the first based on the number in the first tables new_rtg_no column based on other criteria and the reason for getting it is for reporting purposes to essentially separate commissioned, exempt, non-exempt, and part-time employees in accordance to a performance rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `group by` isn't working because each of those selects is an independent uncorrelated subquery.  As an example,

```
(SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
           FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
           WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' )) AS R2E
```

will get you the count from the entire database because there is no `group by` inside it.  Here's what you would need to do for each one, with your current structure:

```
(SELECT     COUNT(NEW_RTG_NO) AS Expr1
           FROM          EMPL AS EMPL_4
           WHERE      (NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E' )
           GROUP BY OPERATION_DESC) AS R2E
```

The issue I see here is that you don't need to do all of these uncorrelated subqueries at all.  I will demonstrate below.  Note that instead of COUNT, I am using a SUM IF.  This is saying, if the condition is met, add one to the sum, otherwise add zero.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OPERATION_DESC, 
    SUM(IF(NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS R1B,
    SUM(IF(NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS R2B,
    SUM(IF(NEW_RTG_NO = 3 AND GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS R3B,
    SUM(IF(NEW_RTG_NO = 4 AND GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS R4B,
    SUM(IF(NEW_RTG_NO = 5 AND GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS R5B,
    SUM(IF(GRADE_CD = '50', 1, 0)) AS TotalBonus,
    **** and so forth ****
FROM empl E
GROUP BY E.OPERATION_DESC 
ORDER BY E.OPERATION_DESC
```

EDIT:

Your original post was tagged with MYSQL, so the above is MYSQL.  I don't work in SQL, so my knowledge of it is from classes I took years ago.  If I remember correctly, you should be able to do something like this for each of those SUM IFs:

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND GRADE_CD = '50'
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
        END) AS R1B,
```

EDIT 2:

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811673/sql-query-sumcase-when-x-then-1-else-0-for-multiple-columns) for other ways of doing it in SQL.

EDIT 3:

There is another method you might want to think about.

```
 SELECT COUNT(r1e.NEW_RTG_NO) AS R1E, COUNT(r2e.NEW_RTG_NO) AS R2E, .... et cetera ....
 FROM empl E
 LEFT JOIN empl r1e ON r1e.NEW_RTG_NO = E.NEW_RTG_NO AND r1e.NEW_RTG_NO = 1 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E'
 LEFT JOIN empl r2e ON r2e.NEW_RTG_NO = E.NEW_RTG_NO AND r2e.NEW_RTG_NO = 2 AND FLSA_STAT_CD = 'E'
 .... et cetera ....
```

I don't know which method is faster in SQL.

Comment: I'm trying to use the new query structure as that was essentially what I was looking for.  I'm now getting Msg 156 syntax error in line 2 near IF, and then subsequent Msg 102 errors in ever line after in the if statement near the "THEN" comma.  However, I'm thinking the subsequent errors are stemming from the first.  Since I'm not using any other tables I should technically be able to get away with not using the table alias, correct?

Comment: Sorry, it was tagged with MYSQL so that's what I used.  I have added what I think is the correct SQL, but I don't have SQL experience.

Comment: Thats fine, I figured it out and it works perfectly.  Marked as answer , plus I'll edit my post with the query that ended up working for me.  Thanks!