# MS Access SUMIIF to SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, case

I'm trying to convert a `MS Access` query to `SQL`, I'm struggling to find the correct way of doing this.

> The MS Access line is: Records Loaded: Sum(IIf([cmp_CampaignTable].>[ContactID]>0,1,0))

The SQL code I have so far is:

```
SELECT        Project.ProjectName, 
                cmp_UKWarranty.ProjectID, 
                SUM(CONVERT(numeric,(CASE WHEN (cmp_UKWarranty.ContactID) >0,1,0) AS RecordsLoaded
FROM            cmp_UKWarranty INNER JOIN
                         Project ON cmp_UKWarranty.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID INNER JOIN
                         Dial ON cmp_UKWarranty.DialID = Dial.DialID CROSS JOIN
                         CRC
```

I have no one else to ask, is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?

Adam

Comment: You are right on track just need the synatx check.[Here you can get more about case in sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) [And this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811673/sql-query-sumcase-when-x-then-1-else-0-for-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case when syntax is wrong :

```
SELECT Project.ProjectName,
       cmp_UKWarranty.ProjectID,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ( cmp_UKWarranty.ContactID > 0 ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)
FROM   cmp_UKWarranty
       INNER JOIN Project
               ON cmp_UKWarranty.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID
       INNER JOIN Dial
               ON cmp_UKWarranty.DialID = Dial.DialID
       CROSS JOIN CRC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.  You need the `then` and `else`.  Also, the conversion to "numeric" is unnecessary:

```
SELECT p.ProjectName, w.ProjectID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN w.ContactID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS RecordsLoaded
FROM cmp_UKWarranty w INNER JOIN
     Project p
     ON w.ProjectID = p.ProjectID INNER JOIN
     Dial d
     ON w.DialID = Dial.d CROSS JOIN
     CRC
```